# Load a whole html within a div like iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I need to display a html page within a div like an iframe with scroll function.

```
<div [innerHtml]="safeHtmlContent | safehtml" style='overflow:auto;
white-space: nowrap; position: static; 
width:500px;height:550px;'>here is some text</div>
```

It works the html content loads, but the issue is the content is not aligned and the sticky header of the html page replaces my header.

So how can I load the html content within the div only.

My sample html content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage" class="html__responsive">
    <head>
        <title>angular - Angular4 Load external html page in a div - Stack Overflow</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
        <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"> ......
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without using `iframe`s you won't be able to do that with the content as-is. [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) is the next best thing, but the sticky header will still be a problem since the browser window is still the view with respect to shadow DOMs where, for `iframe`s, the `iframe` is the view. You might try filtering the content but that seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: You will also have the problem of css files not rendering, javascript pollution and file references breaking (e.g. images)